# Find the function $f(x,y)$ if $f_y(x,y)=x^2+2y$ and $f(x,x^2)=1$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find a function $f(x,y)$ which applies the conditions  $f_y(x,y)=x^2+2y$ and $f(x,x^2)=1$.

I tried to compute $f_x(x,x^2)=f_x(x,x^2)+2xf_y(x,x^2)$ so I get that $f_y(x,x^2)=0$.
I don't really have a direction of how I should solve this. I'd love your help with this one.

Edit: Is there any solution without using integrals? I don't how to integrate with respect to one variable.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $f(x,y)=x^2y+y^2+g(x)$ where $g$ is arbitrary, until you use the second condition. Note that the second condition says that $f(x,x^2)$ is *identically* equal to $1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: integrate $x^2 + 2 y$ with respect to $y$ to get $f(x,y)$ up to an arbitrary function of $x$.  Then use the equation $f(x,x^2)=1$ to see what that arbitrary function of $x$ must be.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please extend your answer?

Comment: Which part don't you get? Do you know how to integrate $x^2+2y$ with respect to $y$?

Comment: Oh, now I see that he wrote integrate and not derivative. so No, I don't know how to integrate with respect to y. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Jozef: If you're learning partial differential equations, I'm sure you can integrate w.r.t. $y$. Just integrate w.r.t. $y$ holding $x$ constant!

Comment: Thanks @CliveNewstead ! Ok, so it's $yx^2+y^2$, I consider it as $f$?

Comment: In fact @Jozef you have $f(x,y)=yx^2+y^2+g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a function (which you have to find too). The function $g(x)$ comes from [constant of integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks!